# Unable to Mock Node fs Modules with Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sinon

I am unable to properly mock the promises methods of the node `fs` module.

My `appData.ts` file calls the real `fs.promises.mkdir` method instead of my mock declared in `\__tests__/appData.test.js`.

I think the problem arises due to how the mocked method is nested within the imported module `fs` as `fs.promises.readdir`. But of course I am not sure.

I know I should be able to debug this issue, but I think I need some help from someone more experienced.

**appData.ts**

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import { app } from 'electron'
const { readdir, mkdir } = fs.promises

/**
 * Initialize app data dir.
 * @param {string} path Where to initialize app data dir.
 */
export async function initDir(path: string): Promise<void> {
  try {
    await readdir(path)
    console.log(`app data dir exists at ${path}`)
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'ENOENT') {
      try {
        await mkdir(path)
        console.log(`created app data dir at ${path}`)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`could not create app data dir at ${path}`)
        console.error(error)
        app.quit()
      }
    } else {
      console.error('unable to handle error while initializing app data dir')
      console.error(error)
      app.quit()
    }
  }
}
```

**__tests__/appData.js**

```
import * as appData from '../appData'
import { stub } from 'sinon'
import * as fs from 'fs'
require('chai').should()

describe('appData', () => {

  describe('initDir()', () => {

    it ('creates app data dir at passed path when it is missing', async () => {
      const noentError = new Error()
      noentError.code = 'ENOENT'
      const readdirStub = stub(fs.promises, 'readdir').throws(noentError)
      const mkdirStub = stub(fs.promises, 'mkdir').resolves(true)
      const expected = 'a/b/c'
      await appData.initDir(expected)
      mkdirStub.args[0][0].should.equal(expected)
    })

  })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the line causing the mock not to work.

**appData.ts**

```
...
const { readdir, mkdir } = fs.promises
...
```

This makes sense to me. It doesn't matter what I mock `fs.promises` methods to be considering that when `appData.ts` is imported, `fs.promises` is destructured into variables that `\__tests__/appData.test.js` cannot touch.

If I want to keep the desctructuring, I can perform it within `initDir()`. This allows `appData.ts` to access the mock `\__tests__/appData.test.js` when `initDir` runs.